# Cant apply a Mixamo animation

Tags: animation, error, mixamo

I've tried two ways to apply a Mixamo animation to my model, I uploaded it to the Mixamo site and when I tried to use the auto-rigger it says "Unknown error while generating motion".

So i tried another way and clicked "Create Control Rig" in Blender, imported the animation and clicked "Apply Animation to Control Rig" but I get this error:

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\mixamo_rig.py", line 306, in execute

_import_anim(src_arm, tar_arm, import_only=True)

File "C:\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\mixamo_rig.py", line 2264, in _import_anim

arm_left_kinematic = "IK" if c_hand_ik_left_pb["ik_fk_switch"] < 0.5 else "FK"

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.